# sending data via ajax to controller is not working

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am developing a shopping cart using codeigniter. When i am sending data via ajax to controller it doesn't works. here is my ajax code i am using
You can check my demo ebsite in this following link

> http://cableandmedia.com/ayurstore/products

```js
$(".add_to_cart").click(function(event) {

  var id=$(this).data('id'); 
 
  var qty=$("#item_"+id).val();
 
  
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url("ajax_controller/add_to_cart/'+id+'/'+qty+'")?>',
            data: { id:id }, 
            success:function(response){
            $("#total_items").html(response);
            $(".view_cart").click();
     }
  });
```

```html
<input type="number"  value="1" id="item_<?php echo $row->product_id; ?>"  />
<a  id="edit_product" data-id="<?php echo $row->product_id; ?>" class="add_to_cart">Add to Cart</a>
```

When I am alert(qty) and alert (id) i am getting the result.
But i am not getting values in my ajax_controller.

This is my controller

```html
public function add_to_cart($pid,$qty)
 {
  $this->load->model('product_model');
  $query=$this->product_model->get_product($pid);
  
  foreach ($query->result() as $row)
  {
      $name=$row->product_name;
      $price=$row->price;
      $img=$row->img_name;
  }
  
  
   $data = array(
               'id'      => $pid,
               'qty'     => $qty,
               'price'   => $price,
               'name'    => $name,
               'options' => array('Status' => 'New')
            );

   $this->cart->insert($data);
   
   echo count($this->cart->contents());
 }
```

Comment: please share your controller code `ajax_controller/add_to_cart`

Comment: Please share your `ajax_controller` controller code @Yadhu Babu

Comment: My issue is that i need to grt that product id and $qty in my ajax controller

Comment: You can see my answer @YadhuBabu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing argument 1 for Ajax_controller::add_to_cart() is the php error that was encounterd.So the problem is with url. product id and quantity are not passed with url.So change the url as below.

```
           <?php echo base_url("ajax_controller/add_to_cart/")?>"+id+"/"+qty
```

Answer (score 3):

**Change ajax url**
You are using java script variables inside the php tag .

```js
$(".add_to_cart").click(function(event) {

  var id=$(this).data('id'); 
 
  var qty=$("#item_"+id).val();
 
  
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo base_url('ajax_controller/add_to_cart/')?>"+id+"/"+qty,
            data: { id:id }, 
            success:function(response){
            $("#total_items").html(response);
            $(".view_cart").click();
     }
  });
```

```html
<input type="number"  value="1" id="item_<?php echo $row->product_id; ?>"  />
<a  id="edit_product" data-id="<?php echo $row->product_id; ?>" class="add_to_cart">Add to Cart</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the value from as ajax as post so try to get it using

In you ajax

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo base_url("ajax_controller/add_to_cart")'?>,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {id: id, qty: qty},
    success: function(res)
```

Write below code in you controller

```
$this->input->post('id');
$this->input->post('qty');
```

Comment: typo missing to close double  quotes close in url:  and you need to escape the double quotes if you use double quotes inside the double quotes

Comment: still one typo in this line find it yourself url: '<?php echo base_url("ajax_controller/add_to_cart")'?>,

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(".add_to_cart").click(function(event) {

  var id=$(this).data('id'); 
 
  var qty=$("#item_"+id).val();
 
  
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url("ajax_controller/add_to_cart/")?>',
            data: { pid:id,qty:qty }, 
            success:function(response){
            $("#total_items").html(response);
            $(".view_cart").click();
     }
  });
```

```html
<input type="number"  value="1" id="item_<?php echo $row->product_id; ?>"  />
<a  id="edit_product" data-id="<?php echo $row->product_id; ?>" class="add_to_cart">Add to Cart</a>
```

Change Controller code like

```
public function add_to_cart()
{
    $pid = $this->input->post('pid');
    $qty = $this->input->post('qty');
    $this->load->model('product_model');
    $query=$this->product_model->get_product($pid);

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $name=$row->product_name;
        $price=$row->price;
        $img=$row->img_name;
    }


        $data = array(
           'id'      => $pid,
           'qty'     => $qty,
           'price'   => $price,
           'name'    => $name,
           'options' => array('Status' => 'New')
        );

        $this->cart->insert($data);

        echo count($this->cart->contents());
}
```